# Retrieve host VM MAC address via guest VM

Tags: c#, virtual-machine

This has been an issue I have been looking to for two days. I will share my findings.

I am currently working on an in-house license management system for our software. It's nothing too fancy - as long as it can uniquely identify a user, it's good enough. Our mechanism currently relies on user sign-in + password + MAC address.

99% of the users so far have had no issues, but there is a small subset, the 1%, that has been returning an issue. This 1% is so important to us, because one failure means one hole in our system, something we would like to weed out. Okay - onto the main topic.

**Method 1:**

```
public static string returnMAC1()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select MACAddress, PNPDeviceID FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE MACAddress IS NOT NULL AND PNPDEVICEID IS NOT NULL");
    ManagementObjectCollection mObject = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in mObject)
    {
        string pnp = obj["PNPDeviceID"].ToString();
        if (pnp.Contains("PCI\\"))
        {
            string mac = obj["MACAddress"].ToString();
            mac = mac.Replace(":", string.Empty);
            return mac;
        }
    }
    return "Nothing happened...";
}
```

Method 1 retrieves the MAC address based on the fact that the physical card is connected to the PCI interface.

**Method 2:**

```
public static string returnMAC2()
{
    string mac = string.Empty;
    foreach (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface nic in System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if (nic.OperationalStatus == System.Net.NetworkInformation.OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
    return mac;
}
```

The second method is a standard method retrieved from MSDN documentation in-regards to MAC addresses.

Based on some tests, it seems the second method is a tad unreliable to retrieve MAC addresses, since it retrieves the wireless card's address. We've had some users returning `null` addresses as a result of using that method, and while I don't know why that would happen, it could be because there's a lack of a wireless card in their computers. With that said, that's only conjecture. *Method #1 relies on using SQL queries to retrieve the PCI MAC. This one has been reliable.*

**Tests:**

Using a Windows 8.1 Enterprise Evaluation edition (free 90-day trial, yay!) installed onto the VirtualBox VM, the tests confirmed that there are major differences in the MAC addresses returned via the guest VM and the host VM.

According to my [research](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_advanced_mac_address.html), in *most* cases, the virtual machine is assigned the same MAC address every time it is powered on, so long as the virtual machine is not moved and no changes are made to the certain settings in the configuration file. With that said, and here's the bad news... The guest VM MAC could be anything. So it seems, this is one of the reasons the MAC addresses are inconsistent when used as unique identifiers, which is an issue I found out when some users were on their company VMs. I never knew that's the way people worked, but here we are, so no gloating about it at this point.

My question is - **is there any way**, without making the user change any settings on their end, **to retrieve the host VM's MAC as opposed to the guest VM?**

At this point I don't see any reason why someone won't assign the same MAC to every single guest machine to get around our floating license mechanism. Retrieving the host VM MAC would get around this issue, as it would show as one MAC.

Comment: What type of host? (VMware, Hyper-V, etc...)

Comment: VirtualBox is the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided this is both impossible and unnecessary. We also decided to use the motherboard UUID as the primary unique identifier, and falling back to the MAC address using the MAC address method below, in case the UUID returns a `FFFF-FFFF.......` on the rare occasion the vendor does not supply a UUID to that motherboard.

```
public static string returnMAC1()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select MACAddress, PNPDeviceID FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE MACAddress IS NOT NULL AND PNPDEVICEID IS NOT NULL");
    ManagementObjectCollection mObject = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in mObject)
    {
        string pnp = obj["PNPDeviceID"].ToString();
        if (pnp.Contains("PCI\\"))
        {
            string mac = obj["MACAddress"].ToString();
            mac = mac.Replace(":", string.Empty);
            return mac;
        }
    }
    return "Nothing happened...";
}
```